# Advice on CSS only pinterest type layout?

Tags: css, pinterest

So I have found a solution for CSS-only Pinterest style layout. I want to use CSS only because jQuery Masonry or whatever just seems less respectable.

I am a complete beginner who has bever coded anything, and I think it'll be easier to just stick to CSS for now and get good in it.

So I want to create a personal website, and I don't mind using JS elsewhere but for the layout I think I want to do it 'from scratch' without cheating with Masonry, and there is a tutorial for this with only a couple problems [cross browser issues and can't order the grids]. http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

This is my question- how do I implement this into a full website?

I know the basic process of writing a website, but I really don't know where to start with making a website using this code. Can someone please give me a step-by-step on how to make a homepage that links to other pages in the website with this?

And how to customise the boxes so that they act as links to other sections of the website?

I want to do it like windows 8 style, where the homepage is made of tiles, you click on a square and it takes you to another section of the website.

HERE is an example of what I am trying to make- http://builtbybuffalo.com/

So in a sense I am asking for a step by step for beginners on how to code the website I just linked to.

Or where to find that info.

Cheers!

Comment: `less respectable` right, ok.

Comment: welcome to SO :] unfortunately, we are not a tutorial site that gives step by step how to's. we offer suggestions and solutions on how to overcome problems a user is stuck on, once the user has demonstrated personal effort on their part. i suggest looking up some tutorials on how to integrate css/stylization into websites

Comment: it kinda is ? and it feels like cheating to me tbh. And as I said I want to get my hands as dirty as possible, to do it from scratch as much as possible so I learn more.

Comment: thanks indubitablee!

Comment: You really would be better off looking for some detailed tutorials elsewhere and then if you get stuck on a certain topic come back here and get help with that, as it would be a very long and probably un-detailed post if posted here.

Comment: There is a reason everyone (including Pinterest) uses javascript to lay out their grids, cross-browser support. Most IE users are pretty screwed with CSS only layouts, and javascript gives you much better support for transitions, etc.